# Return toaddress of a singlemailmeessage

Tags: apex, visualforce, singleemailmessage

I am trying to do the following
the `singleemailmessage` has been created here.

```
public List<String> getToAddresses(){
       System.debug('toaddress'+singleEmailMessage.toaddresses);
           return singleEmailMessage.toaddresses;

       }
```

The mail is being sent. But the method given above is not returning the toaddresses. Can anyone tell me where am i going wrong

Comment: As per the doc. It should return toAddress https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound.htm#apex_Messaging_InboundEmail_toAddresses

Answer (score 1):

The documentation indicates 'toAddresses', not 'toaddresses' (you need a capital 'A').